# visual studio 2010 c++ collapse a specific macro

Tags: visual-studio-2010, macros

I have a lot of code that contain a macro used for logging LOG_MACRO and I want to collapse this in all my solution to better understanding the code.
Do know any visual studio options or tools that I can use to collapse my macro?
I have visual assist but I can`t found nothing to do this.

Thanks

```
void ClassA::FuncA()
{
    LOG_MACRO( LogA, LogB, Log1,
      ("ClassA::FuncA - IN - id:[%x]", this ) );

   if ( ...condition here... )
   {
      ...code here...
   }

    LOG_MACRO( LogA, LogB, Log1,
      ("ClassA::FuncA - END" ) );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could open your macro source file in [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/)